# Oracle database error ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle10g

This query shows error on execution:

```
SELECT City,Company 
  FROM invoicelist 
 WHERE Company='Filmfare'
  AND City='Ahmedabad' AND size= 20;
```

I created this table using this create statement:

```
create table invoicelist(
    "city" varchar(20),
    "company" varchar(20), 
    "month" varchar(20),
    "size" varchar(20), 
    "des" varchar(500)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you quote identifiers with `"` they become case sensitive.

So either you

```
select "city"  ....
```

or you create your table without `"`

```
create table invoicelist(
  city     varchar(20),
  company  varchar(20), 
  month    varchar(20),
  size     varchar(20), 
  des      varchar(500)
);
```

*BTW*, may I recommend you use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: thanx but using the above create statement it gives :                          ORA-00904: : invalid identifier